# Which carrier has extensive cellular coverage in Sicily?

Tags: internet, data-plans, sicily

I'm visiting Sicily for two weeks as a tourist and I need a good and reliable cellular Internet connection to use on my iPhone and iPad.

Does anyone have data on what coverage is offered by the different carriers, with hopefully 4G speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check [opensignal.com](http://opensignal.com/coverage-maps/Italy/), they have a map showing coverage - from that it would seem coverage on Sicily is below average for Italy; and I can tell you Italy in general is below average compared to other european countries.

That said, it seem I TIM (Telecom Italia) is the only provider actually covering the whole of Sicily, with Vodafone and 3 on second and third place and WIND coming in last.

[sensorly.com](http://www.sensorly.com/map/2G-3G/IT/Italy/TIM/gsm_22201#%7Ccoverage) shows an overall better coverage in Sicily, but the trend between the providers seems the same.