# Mobile phones and mobile internet in Italy

Tags: cellphones, italy, internet, data-plans, mobile-operators

Buongiorno!
Suppose I step down from the plain in Fiumicino. What is the fastest way to get hold of Italian SIM-card with some talking minutes and some Internet? The latter is more important than the former.

So, my requirements:

- Good coverage in main cities (Rome, Venice, Milan, Florence)
- Good for 2 weeks (after that I'm going to leave the country, the SIM is going to lose its value anyway)
- Good for massive internet usage is in store for maps, orientation, etc.
- Cheap. :)

Now, I know that there are 3 main communication providers in Italy: Vodafone, Wind and the third one. :) Which one? Which one won't leave me destitute and won't sue me over the border months after for some unknown reasons? What I have to look for?

Comment: TIM is the third one. There is also 3. And some low-cost operators have recently joined the market.

Comment: Thank you )
Looks like someone has downvoted me. I wonder, why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage in Italy is good across all three main operators: TIM Vodafone and Wind. I would suggest Wind for it's value for money. With Wind you can get 100 minutes, 200 sms and 1GB for 10€ + 1€ (activation cost). They call this [All Inclusive Ricaricabile](http://www.wind.it/index.php?id=9175). They also have an Internet-only offer giving you 3GB for 9€, which will however expire soon (8th February). See [here](http://www.wind.it/it/privati/tariffe_e_opzioni/internet/offerte_internet/open_internet_3gb/) for more details.

Vodafone recently swiched their pay-as-you-go plans to a [senseless rolling contract scheme](http://www.vodafone.it/portal/Privati/Tariffe-e-Prodotti/Tariffe/Ricaricabili/offerte-scegli-tu-vodafone?icmp=Scegli_tu_Prospect), forcing you to pay a minimum of 10€ to get a lousy 100MB of internet. TIM too [switched to a similar system](http://www.tim.it/tariffe/chiamate-sms-internet). Both this carriers however offer internet-only plans, [here](http://www.vodafone.it/portal/Privati/Tariffe-e-Prodotti/Prodotti/sim-piani-internet) for Vodafone and [here](http://www.tim.it/internet/offerte-internet-per-smartphone) for TIM.

Comment: Thank you! I also was looking at wind offers, just thought I ought to check it independently.

Comment: Also [PosteMobile](http://www.postemobile.it/), you have an option for which you buy "credits" each of which amounts to 1 SMS, 1 Minute or 1 Mega. It's good if you plan on doing all three, but do not know if you will need hundreds of minutes or texts.

Answer (score 0):

The four main providers are: TIM, Vodafone, 3 and WIND.

Generally the provider is required to request your *codice fiscale* when opening a contract or giving you a prepaid SIM. Some vendors will refuse to give you a SIM if you do not have a codice fiscale, others will take a copy of your passport and simply ['calculate' your codice fiscale](http://www.comuni.it/servizi/codfisc/) ([alternative calculator here](http://www.codicefiscale.com/)).

Once you have a SIM, it may take up to 48h for the SIM to be activated (this depends on system loads and vendor - TIM and Vodafone tend to be faster than 3 and WIND).

Regarding coverage you may want to [see here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35225/which-carrier-has-extensive-cellular-coverage-in-sicily/35226#35226) and the links therein. Generally Vodafone and TIM have quite good coverage across most of Italy with 3 not far behind. WIND is comparable in the north, but falls back considerably when south of Rome and also is less reliable outside the cities.